# Retrieving the Handle of a Windows Native File Browser generated by QFileBrowser

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, handle

I am trying to create a GUI testing demo for a QT application. I know I am able to use QTestLib to interact with QT widgets, but I am having issues trying to interact with native popups generated by certain parts of our application.

One such instance is the static `QFileBrowser` like `getOpenFileName()`, which generates a browser native to the OS of the machine by default (in this case, it is Windows), and this is what we use for our application's file browsers.

I am having some trouble trying to access the handle of the native file browser generated by the code.

Once I called `QFileBrowser::getOpenFileName()`, I ran a thread that would find the `QFileDialog` widget found within the `QApplication::topLevelWidgets()`, and then get the `HWND` through the `QWidgets::winId()` and try to access its child handles like below:

```cpp
QWidgetList popups = QApplication::topLevelWidgets();

for (auto* widget : popups)
{
    if (widget->inherits("QFileDialog"))
    {
        QFileDialog* mb = qobject_cast<QFileDialog*>(widget);

        HWND fileDialogHandle = (HWND)mb->winId();

        // Find the handle to the child buttons
        // Both of these handles return null
        HWND openButtonHandle = FindWindowEx(fileDialogHandle, NULL, L"Button", L"&Open");
        HWND cancelButtonHandle = FindWindowEx(fileDialogHandle, NULL, L"Button", L"&Cancel");

        // Click the "Open" button
        SendMessage(openButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);

        // Click the "Cancel" button
        SendMessage(cancelButtonHandle, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);;
 
        QApplication::processEvents();
    }
}
```

The actual handle of the native file browser that I see via Visual Studio Spy++ is different from the handle in the code. As far as I can tell, they are not related to each other either.

Property of the `QFileDialog` handle, and the actual file browser's handle:

[image]

I wonder if there is a way for me to reliably get the actual handle of the native file browser dialog generated by `QFileBrowser`? Would I have better luck making my own custom file browser functions?

Comment: Even if you could get the proper `HWND` of the native dialog window, using `FindWindowEx()` and `BM_CLICK` is the wrong way to interact with its child controls.

Comment: Yeah those are just some things I have tried out, but have not been able to really prove due to the aforementioned issue with being able to fetch the native dialog window. I wonder if it's best to just implement my own windows file browsers at this point

Comment: I can't find any documentation on `QFileBrowser`, but the documentation for [`QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) clearly says: "*On Windows, and macOS, this static function will use the native file dialog **and not a QFileDialog**.*" So, I would have to assume that your `widget->inherits("QFileDialog")` check on the entries of `QApplication::topLevelWidgets()` won't be able to find the dialog at all